# Error while sending POST request to API (Cannot send a body with this verb type)

Tags: c#, api, post, webclient

I always get this error when I try to request the API.
Some details about the api : the method is POST and the parameters are correct, too (When I try it on postman, no issue)

Here is my code:

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    foreach (var ad in documents)
    {

        var doc = js.Serialize(ad);
        var json = "{\"Message\":\"" + doc + "\"}";

        var response =
            client.UploadValues("apiUrl", new NameValueCollection()
            {
                {"json", json}
            });
    }
}
```

I read that UploadValues is POST by default. This code is called in a simple console app. Any idea why I get this error ?

Comment: Both `WebClient` and `JavaScriptSerializer` are mostly deprecated, you should be using `HttpClient` with `NewtonSoft.Json`

Comment: `var json = "{\"Message\":\"" + doc + "\"}";` Yuk. Why build it by hand? It's just asking for un-catchable syntax errors. You're already using a serializer (albeit an out of date one) and a NameValueCollection, so why randomly create a string in the middle of that? Anyway, if it works in Postman but not in this, the first thing you should do is use a tool like Fiddler to intercept both requests and then play spot the difference between the actual HTTP requests generated by the two different pieces of software.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, it's working with this code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working piece of code :

```
var doc = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);    
var stringContent = new StringContent(
        message,
        UnicodeEncoding.UTF8,
        "application/json");

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();                

client.PostAsync("apiUrl", stringContent);
```